# Difficulty loading .rdata file because of name

Tags: r

I'm trying to load an .rdata file into R, but facing difficulty. The problem is with the original name of the .rdata file. It has the character '-' in it, which R reads as a minus sign, which means I cannot save the data and work with it. Code and error below.

```
load("/Users/hemingway1/Desktop/WVS3.rdata")
ls()
#  [1] "a"                       "a1"                      "b"                      
#  [4] "b1"                      "estBetaParams"           "model"                  
#  [7] "model_string"            "mu"                      "n"                      
# [10] "samp"                    "theta"                   "var"                    
# [13] "WV3_Data_R_v_2015-04-18" "WVS3"                    "y"    

WVS3 <- WV3_Data_R_v_2015-04-18
```

> Error: object 'WV3_Data_R_v_2015' not found

Comment: Try to use backticks around `WV3_Data_R_v_2015-04-18`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of backticks is generally the solution to solve this kind of problem. Here, the solution would be:

```
WVS3 <- `WV3_Data_R_v_2015-04-18`
```